# Prevent Apache2 from logging robots and image requests

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files

I run a high-traffic site and I need to reign in my Apache2 access logs a bit. One way to do this, I've read, is to limit the types of things Apache2 logs. The obvious choice would be, to limit 3 types of requests:

1. Requests made by bots
2. Requests for images, js files, and css (I'm only interested in the page request. Not ALL the assets)
3. Requests made by localhost (the web server itself)

I am running the Apache2 mod [setinf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) but it doesn't look like any of my changes take affect when I `tail -f` my access log. I'm also running cronolog (if that matters) as a log rotator. Here's what is in my VirtualHost conf:

```
# LogLevel warn

# Variable is_local_referrer = requests made by the server itself
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://*.mysite.com/" is_local_referrer

# Variable dont_log = standard file requests
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".(jpg|jpeg|png|css|gif|ico|js)$" dont_log

# Variable is_a_robot = user agent is a robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent Robot is_a_robot

ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/me/public/mysite.com/log/error_%Y_%m.log"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/me/public/mysite.com/log/access_%Y_%m.log" combined env=!is_local_referrer|!dont_log|!is_a_robot
```

Again, when I tail /usr/bin/cronolog /home/me/public/mysite.com/log/access_X_X.log Apache2 is logging every single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe (and the documentation doesn't suggest) that you can make a CustomLog statement like `env=!is_local_referrer|!dont_log|!is_a_robot`, i.e., across several environmental variables.

You can have all of the SetEnvIf statments set the "dont_log" and then just say `env=!dont_log`, or you can have other SetEnvIf statements operate on the other env variables to set some other variable which will be used in the CustomLog directive, in case you're using, say, `is_local_referrer` elsewhere, e.g.:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://*.mysite.com/" is_local_referrer
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".(jpg|jpeg|png|css|gif|ico|js)$" is_static_asset
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent Robot is_a_robot

SetEnvIf is_local_referrer .* dont_log
SetEnvIf is_static_asset .* dont_log
SetEnvIf is_a_robot .* dont_log
```

That ".*" is to fulfill the syntax requirements shown at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif and there may be a better way to do this, as I haven't tested this configuration.  Maybe you can set, e.g., `is_local_referrer=1` and then regex on `1` in the "dont_log" statements.

Comment: Yep. That's it. The version I wrote is a little different (I just renamed all the variables to "dont_log" and then had a single env=!dont_log at the end. Either way works. Thanks!